# How to convert A to \x41

Tags: python-2.7, hex

Hi i am trying to generate a hex dump of file using Python, in \x format, If input contains A output should be \x41, if input is 0x41 output should be \x41 and it has to be written to another file.
SO far i could do was 
    `

```
content = "ABCDE"
for i in xrange(len(content)):
    s = hex(ord(content[i]))
    fw.write(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`format(value, 'X')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) to convert the unicode to hex, before appending it to your prefix. Remember to escape the backslash.

```
for i in list(content):
    s = "\\x" + format(ord(i), 'X')
```